# How do I interactively unstage a particular hunk in git?

Tags: git, staging

In git, if I have a couple of hunks from the same file staged in my index, how can I interactively unstage one of them?

Is there any alternative to unstaging the entire file, and then re-staging the hunks I want to keep, or manually undoing the changes to the working copy, and then interactively adding those undone changes?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Try `git reset --patch filename`; this should do the opposite of `git add --patch`, according to the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). The short form `-p` also works for both commands.

Comment: I don't think my version has it (it's 1.6.3.3), but this looks like the correct answer.

Comment: In that case (and assuming that you cannot upgrade for some reason), I suggest that you use `git stash save --keep-index` to save and reset your current working copy changes. Then, you can reset your file and undo the changes you don't want. If you copy the file to some temporary location first, you can use `diff` to save the changes you undo. Then, you can add the file back again (no need for an interactive add since you stashed away the other changes you weren't interested in). Use `git stash pop` to get back the old changes, and `diff` to apply the changes you undid. Quite cumbersome... :-(

Comment: `The short form -p also works for both commands.`.. You mean `git reset -p filename`?

Comment: @Nawaz: That's correct - `git add -p filename` selectively stages changes from that file, and `git reset -p filename` selectively unstages changes. There's also `git checkout -p -- filename`, which lets you selectively discard changes from a file. Warning: each of `add` and `reset` can be used to undo the other of the two, but if you use this form of `checkout` to discard a change, you can't get it back.

Answer (score 5):

`git gui` has a decent GUI to interactively stage or unstage hunks or lines. There are prettier/better GUI clients, but `git gui` is lightweight, built-in, and cross platform (lin, win, mac).

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui

Simply right click on a hunk to stage/unstage. For lines, highlight the lines first, then right click.

Comment: `git gui` does this in an excellent way. I wonder if there is a non-GUI way, to use in a terminal when e.g. being connected to a Linux server.

Answer (score -1):

[GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) has a nice UI for unstaging chunks of a file:
[image]

The official client hasn't been maintained in a while, but [a fork over at GitHub](https://github.com/brotherbard/gitx) with more features is popular in some circles. ([blog post about it](http://brotherbard.com/blog/2010/03/experimental-gitx-fork/))

Comment: For the Windows users out there, [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) has a similarly nice UI.

Comment: So does the built in `git gui`, except I'm not sure I'd use the word "nice" ;)

Comment: [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (Windows + Mac) also has a nice UI for this.

Comment: I should mention the more recent graphical Git clients now -- [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) is beautiful, and supports this (though it now comes with a hefty fee for commercial use). GitHub's [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) is free, beautiful, and supports easily staging and unstaging hunks. GitKraken and GitHub Desktop are both cross-platform, but neither are open-source.